# Rails - Nexmo api replay from mobile phones to my application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vonage

I'm using ruby on rails. I am using the Nexmo test account and I am trying to implement the callback functionality from my mobile phone. It means when I send the SMS to my mobile, then I want to send replay from my mobile to my application through the Nexmo API.

Is this feature available on the Nexmo API? Please let me know if there are any solutions, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are looking for their Inbound SMS API service. You configure a callback url which Nexmo will post the SMS details to when someone sends your Nexmo number an SMS it will be posted to your app.

https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/sms-api/handle-inbound-message